# Why did season 2 of Krunker.io affect all market item prices?

Tags: krunker.io

I noticed that **Krunker.io** had an *update* and has a new **season (2)**. But after that, all items on the **Krunker market** were affected, and the items from **season 1** became obsolete or devalued. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this can be compared to real life, when all things are temporary. Like, if you have a car, it's price change every year, because new cars are being released and therefore, your car is subject to changes. Comparing this to the *Krunker market*, the tendency, in this case, is that **the most beautiful and new items are more valued by Krunker players**.

As a clear example, this graphic below shows that, before **SEASON 2**, the average sale price of this assault rifle (AK Gold Rush in this case) was much **higher** (around 1200 KR).

[image: AK Gold Rush average sale price graph]